# YouTube Api - Could not search: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, json, youtube, youtube-api

I have been following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858) to create Youtube application.. I created Browser-Android API Key and tried both of them in my project.. But when I try to run it and search I get:

```
Could not search: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
   "code" : 403,
   "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "usageLimits",
     "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
     "reason" : "ipRefererBlocked",
     "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com"
   } ],
   "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
 }
```

Any Idea..?

Comment: I did, and I'm sure it's the right one.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed by setting the referers of the browser api to any referer allowed.

Comment: i have API key and serch EngineId , though i have error. so i think in my case if billing information need to be filled.

Comment: is it necessary to filled billing information to use API?

Answer (score 2):

All you've to do is : 
***Remove/Edit Referers to "Any referer allowed"*** from the section of
"Key for browser applications" .

Answer (score 0):

Setting it to "Any referer allowed" is easy as erasing all referer allowed inputs.