# Youtube API v3 ipRefererBlocked

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I try to search using the Youtube API.

but, received this message 'ipRefererBlocked'

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc0dx.png]

The following image is my API settings

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uBeh.png]

please give me the way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `per-IP` or `per-Referer` restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from P or referer should be allowed. Your request was blocked because it came from an IP address that didn't match the IP restrictions for that key.

That implies you have created a server API key, while what you want is an ios client API key. Make sure you are requesting the [YouTube scope](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) as part of sign in as well.

Every request must either specify an API key or provide an [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) token. Your API key is available in the Developer Console's API Access pane for your project.

Here's a related SO ticket, you may use the work around offered by community: [Youtube API permission 403 Forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591012/youtube-api-permission-403-forbidden-error) and [YouTube Api - Could not search: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356313/youtube-api-could-not-search-com-google-api-client-googleapis-json-googlejson)

Comment: Specifically, your 2nd screenshot shows the API key will only accept requests from http://127.0.0.1:59 so check your server.